# Compare two 2D numpy arrays and remove rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two 2D numpy arrays

```
a = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5]] b = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]
```

How do I do b-a as in remove rows in b that are found in a?

The answer I need is `c = [[6,7,8]]`

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really have numpy arrays? Note they are not same as lists.

Comment: yes they are ndarrays

Comment: Do they have to be in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   for j in range(len(b)):
       if(b[j] == a[i]):
           b.pop(j)
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension here:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5]] 
b = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

result = [x for x in b if x not in a]
print(result)
```

Output :

```
[[6, 7, 8]]
```